# How to remove something from the Box in Plotly Python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, seaborn

Which line of this code:

```
# Take credit amount values into a list
young = df['Credit_amount'].loc[df['Age_Group'] == 'Young'].values.tolist()
young_adults = df['Credit_amount'].loc[df['Age_Group'] == 'Young Adults'].values.tolist()
senior = df['Credit_amount'].loc[df['Age_Group'] == 'Senior'].values.tolist()
elder_credit = df['Credit_amount'].loc[df['Age_Group'] == 'Elder'].values.tolist()

# Create the box plots by age category
young_credit = go.Box(
    y = young,
    name = "Young",
    jitter = 0.3,
    pointpos = -1.8,
    boxpoints = 'all',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(150, 198, 109)'),
    line = dict(
        color = 'rgb(111, 200, 37)')
)

young_adults_credit = go.Box(
    y = young_adults,
    name = "Young Adults",
    jitter = 0.3,
    pointpos = -1.8,
    boxpoints = 'all',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(124, 236, 212)'),
    line = dict(
        color = 'rgb(38, 214, 177)')
)

senior_credit = go.Box(
    y = senior,
    name = "Seniors",
    jitter = 0.3,
    pointpos = -1.8,
    boxpoints = 'all',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(241, 93, 93)'),
    line = dict(
        color = 'rgb(225, 44, 44)')
)

elder_credit = go.Box(
    y = elder_credit,
    name = "Elders",
    jitter = 0.3,
    pointpos = -1.8,
    boxpoints = 'all',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(180, 121, 72)'),
    line = dict(
        color = 'rgb(115, 77, 46)')
)

data = [young_credit, young_adults_credit, senior_credit, elder_credit]

layout = dict(
    title="Credit Amount by Age Group Segment", 
    xaxis = dict(title="Age Group"),
    yaxis= dict(title="Credit Amount")
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename="Box Plot")
```

concerns the fragments marked in the picture below, I would like to remove those fragments from the chart and which lines of code I have to remove to achieve this goal.
I will be really thankfull for all clear answers because I can not find line of code to remove this fragments of plot.
Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: How did the suggested solutions work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you Want to totally remove the points, you should remove parameters in each go.Box:

```
jitter = 0.3,
pointpos = -1.8,
boxpoints = 'all'
```

Answer (score 1):

From [plot.ly/python/box-plots/](https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/): With the `points` argument, display underlying data points with either all points (`all`), outliers only (`outliers`, default), or none of them (**False**).

**Plot 1:** `boxpoints = False`

[image]

**Plot 2:** `boxpoints = 'all'`

[image]

Comment: This should be the way to do it - but it seems that it has a weird behavior. See this (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/277) issue. You can't see the effect in this example (because there are no outliers - everything is within the whiskers) but setting bospoints=False will change the way the whiskers are calculated and extend them to capture outliers (up to 5% and 95% percentile I think). Just keep in mind..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and can still not find the fix. The github issue is still open which Ahmed mentioned (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/277).

Although, you can use a visible work around. It does not fix the problem! But for the vision it is fixed.
You van `marker=dict(opacity=0)` which makes the points invisible. When you hover over them, they are still there.